# Are PhDs in Engineering worth it for working in the labour market?

Tags: phd, masters, career-path, engineering, electrical-engineering

I am a undergraduate electrical engineering student in Canada. Programming courses aren't offered in our EE degree. So, to overcome this lack, I learned to program in Java, C++ and in Python by my own. I also learned to use Git and to do bash scripting, with a colleague of mine who wants to work as a developer.

By learning by my own, I discovered that I liked microcontroller programming and programming in general. I maybe want to pursue a professional career in electronic engineering, in computer engineering or in software engineering, but I know that I will not be qualified enough compared to someone with a CS degree.

Hence, I started looking at doing a Master's degree in Computer Engineering or in Electronics Engineering, after I'm graduated from my B. Eng. I found some informations about course-based master's degree that could help me get on the labour market, so I can get accredited as a P.Eng. with professional work experience.

But, my parents, who both work at a university (my mom is a professor), want me to become a university professor. For this purpose, they push me to do a PhD, and therefore a thesis-based master's degree.

So, I wanted to know if PhDs in Engineering are worth it for working in the labour market. If yes, could I simply work as an electronics or computer engineer, with a PhD ?

Comment: What "labour market"? Shovelling cow manure or designing a power station?

Comment: I think there's a background question here that's strictly on-topic: What are good reasons to pursue a PhD? Making your parents happy is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

This heavily depends on your local circumstances. Nobody can answer this for you - you must find out for yourself.

Go to your local jobs portal (Google for one if you don't know what they are) and search for jobs requiring a degree in engineering. Then repeat the search for jobs requiring a Masters in engineering, and jobs requiring a PhD in engineering. Which jobs do you find the most attractive? How much is their estimated pay? How much would that premium be worth over the course of your estimated working life? How much time & money would have to put to acquire that premium?

Once you have the answers to these questions, you can move on to the big one: is it worth it?